# How to convert an ArrayList<double[]> to a double[] array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, double

I want to parse a value from Activity B back to Activity A. The values which should be parsed back has the following format:

```
ArrayList<double[]>
```

because each List entry has two values.
For example: 0: 12;14 1: 14;17

Now for parsing them back I need a the

```
ArrayList<double[]> converted back to a double[] array.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Comment: plz share the code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    ArrayList<double[]> list = ...
    double[][] a = list.toArray(new double[list.size()][]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok just found a solution:

```
double[][] returnvalue = new double[resultat.size()][resultat.size()];

for(int i =0;i<resultat.size();i++)
{
    returnvalue[i] = resultat.get(i);
}
```